# Could "It needn't have been Jill that wrote the note" be interpreted other than deontic?

Tags: modal-verbs, deontic-vs-epistemic, modality

I know that the modality can be ambiguous and many clauses can be interpreted in many ways. I find that the clause "It needn't have been Jill that wrote the note" can be interpreted as deontic, but is dynamic also an option or not?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Since when is *dynamic* one of the two modal dualities? You're going to have to define the terms you're using here.

Comment: The epistemic reading is, without further context, in my opinion the default sense: 'It's not necessarily Jill who wrote the note.'

Comment: Compare *Jill didn’t need to write the note* (obligation) and *Jill didn’t necessarily write the note* (possibility). You can read your example either way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the terminology of Huddleston & Pullum, there are three forms of modality: epistemic, deontic, and dynamic. Following their rules around negation, we can roughly rephrase your sentence to use each of those three unambiguously:

1. *Epistemic:* It is not known whether Jill was the one who wrote the note.
2. *Dynamic:* Jill had the ability/capacity not to be the one who wrote the note.
3. *Deontic:* Jill was not obligated/required to be the one who wrote the note.

"It needn't have been Jill that wrote the note" could be interpreted as (1); you could use the sentence in the epistemic sense to correct someone who claimed that Jill was certainly the author.

It could also be interpreted as (3); you could use that sentence in the deontic sense to point out that someone else could have taken on the task.

But the interpretation (2) does not seem plausible. It seems like a quite unusual use of the word "need," and it's an odd idea to express semantically in context. You would use it to (say) refute the idea that Jill was coerced into writing the note.

Comment: The interpretation I think most likely is "Jill wrote the note, but it was possible for someone else to write it."

Comment: @Barmar The word "possible" is also ambiguous between different modal interpretations, so I'm not quite sure what you're trying to say.

Comment: I'm trying to say anyone might have written it, but it happened to be Jill. Ugh, "might" also has multiple modalities. This is really hard!

Comment: My point is that it's not about ability, it's expressing a potential counterfactual.

Comment: @Barmar Do you mean "other people were physically/mentally capable of writing it" or "it would have been permissible/acceptable for other people it write it"? The former is dynamic, the latter deontic.

Comment: Consider when there's a group of people responsible for taking an action, and one of them (Jill) actually takes it. It might have been any of them, it needn't have been Jill.

Comment: @Barmar That's deontic.

Answer (score 1):

Let's think about what the sentence is saying and then what it is doing.

It is equivalent (in truth value) to the following propositions:

1. The statement "Jill wrote the note" is not necessarily true.
2. The statement "Jill wrote the note" may/might not be true.

Proposition 1 is true if and only if something like 1a is true:-

1a. The statement "Jill did not write the note" does not contradict anything we know to be true about Jill or the note.

Proposition 2 looks (and is) more uncertain than this.  "May"/"might" are modal forms.  If I say "I might/may come and see you tomorrow", my appearance or non-appearance at your house tomorrow makes no difference to the truth or otherwise of my statement.  It is not a prediction or a promise.  It is modal.  So is 'need' as in 'She need not have' done it.  If it turns out that she did in fact do the deed, even this does not make the sentence wrong.

As to 'deontic', meaning 'to do with obligation or necessity'. The Routledge Encyclopaedia of Philosophy explains it thus:

> Modality, as it is usually understood in contemporary philosophy, has to do with necessities and possibilities. Deontic modality is a kind of modality which has to do with what is necessary or possible according to various rules, such as the norms of morality, the principles of practical rationality or the laws of some country. Deontic modality can be contrasted with alethic modality and epistemic modality. The former has to do with what propositions are necessarily or possibly true given various metaphysical, logical or nomological laws. The latter has to do with what propositions are necessarily or possibly true given various bodies of evidence or information.

Words commonly thought to express deontic modalities include the auxiliary verbs ‘must’, ‘have to’, ‘may’, ‘can’, ‘should’ and ‘ought to ’...  On these criteria, I think it would be fair to use the term *deontic*.

Comment: If it's talking about probability, possibility, and likelihood, it's epistemic. One-place modals, no authority expressed, no duties or permissions involved. Logical, not social. That's epistemic. _Not need to_ (itself a negative polarity item in its modal structure) is interpreted as `Possible Not`. So Jill was maybe not the author, if it needn't have been her that wrote it.

Comment: @John Lawler.  Somehow, I put my summary of what follows the quotation from the Routledge entry, but in my own words, for the sake of brevity.  Routledge in any case includes the wider concept of "practical rationality".  It is clear from this and  alternative analysis from Huddleston and Pullam.  This is an illustration of the way in which alternative analyses of the same grammatical feature are possible.  You pays your money and you takes you pick as to which is the more perspicuous.  Each in its own way offers a tenable way of understanding the phenomenon.

Comment: But Huddleston and Pullum is not about logic or modality; it's an English grammar using novel terminology, and it is not authoritative on logic or semantics.

Comment: What about this interpretation: "It's true that Jill wrote the note, but it wasn't necedssarily the case"?